# Ajax request with else statement not well responding

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Ajax with a form to show user on submit whether all went fine (no error) or if an input is missing. It should be basic.. I'm using the XMLHttpRequest object. The form got four fields, all required. I'm new at using Ajax, your help would be very great

Here is my form

```
<form method="POST">
        @csrf
        <!-- Intitulé du thème -->
        <input type="text" name="intitule" id="intitule" placeholder="Intitulé du thème" required><br>
        <!-- Catégorie -->
        <select name="categorie" required>
            <option value="">-- Catégorie --</option>
            <option value="web">Développement web</option>
            <option value="appMobile">Programmation application mobile</option>
            <option value="secure">Sécurisation</option>
            <option value="other">Autre</option>
        </select> <br>
        <!-- Filière désirée -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="GL" value="GL" required>
        <label for="GL">Génie Logiciel</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="SI" value="SI" required>
        <label for="SI">Sécurité Informatique</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="IM" value="IM" required>
        <label for="IM">Internet et Multimédia</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="SIRI" value="SIRI" required>
        <label for="SIRI">Systèmes d'Information et Réseaux Informatiques</label><br>
        <!-- Descriptif -->
        <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description de la thématique" required></textarea><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Ajouter">
        <span id="error-message" class="text-danger"></span>
        <span id="success-message" class="text-success"></span>
    </form>
```

In my jquery code I declared a variable `itsChecked` to have a value when a checkbox is checked or not.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            var itsChecked = null;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
                if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){ //S'il y a au moins 1 ([...].length > 0) ckecked
                alert('At least one is checked');
                    itsChecked = 1;
                    $('#GL').removeAttr("required");
                    $('#SI').removeAttr("required");
                    $('#IM').removeAttr("required");
                    $('#SIRI').removeAttr("required");
                }
                else if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){ //S'il n'y a aucun checked (!(at least 1)>0)
                alert('None is checked');
                    itsChecked = 0;
                    $('#GL').attr('required','');
                    $('#SI').attr('required','');
                    $('#IM').attr('required','');
                    $('#SIRI').attr('required','');

            }
            });
```

For the Ajax part, I've used the XHR object.

```
            $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

                var titre = $('#intitule').val();
                var domaine = $('select[name=categorie]').val();
                var filiereChecked = [];
                $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){            

                filiereChecked.push($(this).val());

                });
                var checked = filiereChecked.join(", ");
                var desc = $('#description').val();
                alert(itsChecked);

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)){
                        // alert(xhr.responseText);
                        // console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        $('#error-message').html('');
                        $('#success-message').fadeIn().html(xhr.responseText);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow');
                        }, 2000);   
                        $('form').trigger('reset'); 
                    }
                    else if (titre == '' || domaine == '' || itsChecked == null || itsChecked == 0 || desc == ''){

                        $('#error-message').fadeIn().html('Tous les champs sont requis');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#error-message').fadeOut('slow');
                        },2000);
                        xhr.abort();
                    }
                };
                var url = "{{ route('themes.store') }}"; 
                var formValues = $("form").serialize();
                xhr.open('POST', url , true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send(formValues);

            });
```

My problem is on the else statement. The verification for `titre`, `domaine` and `desc` is ok: I mean, when their fields are not informed, the error message is returned and the user have to fill all of them.

The exception is with checkbox group. Here comes the itsChecked variable to help. So when it is 'null' or equals 0, the same process should be followed and the user will have to fill properly. Somehow, when it is not checked, I'm getting the error message but the form is still submitted in the database with that checkbox field empty (NULL) in the database. I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong here. 
Thanks to help

Comment: how about type checking `(titre === '' || domaine === '' || itsChecked === null || itsChecked === 0 || desc === '')` ?

Comment: @toing_toing just tried, it's not working either

Comment: tried adding adding a `return false` statement after the `abort()`? abort doesn't close the connection with the server, so message MIGHT still be sent as you are calling the send method outside the if else.

Comment: change the initial itsChecked to var itsChecked = "nothing", then if its unchecked instead of 0 set it to itsChecked ="unchecked" then instead of 1 change it to itsChecked = "checked"  then in you ajax else if change null to "nothing" and 0 to "unchecked"

Comment: @toing_toing, did what you proposed, but weirdly I think.. I'm getting the same results: data still submitted with the checkbox field despite it being empty. Also, I thought about that send method outside but am I supposed to write that differently?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian, did it, same problem persists..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think your logic is flawed. You are trying to put an unnecessary `else` in both your conditional statements. Also, the form is posted whenever the submit button is called as the `send()` is out of the conditional statements. Try to understand how form validation works, and specially what [`xhr.onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) and similar methods achieve. Here's how I would look at your problem:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
    @csrf
    <!-- Intitulé du thème -->
    <input type="text" name="intitule" id="intitule" placeholder="Intitulé du thème" required>
    <br>
    <!-- Catégorie -->
    <select name="categorie" required>
        <option value="">-- Catégorie --</option>
        <option value="web">Développement web</option>
        <option value="appMobile">Programmation application mobile</option>
        <option value="secure">Sécurisation</option>
        <option value="other">Autre</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <!-- Filière désirée -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="GL" value="GL" required>
    <label for="GL">Génie Logiciel</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="SI" value="SI" required>
    <label for="SI">Sécurité Informatique</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="IM" value="IM" required>
    <label for="IM">Internet et Multimédia</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="SIRI" value="SIRI" required>
    <label for="SIRI">Systèmes d'Information et Réseaux Informatiques</label>
    <br>
    <!-- Descriptif -->
    <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description de la thématique" required></textarea>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Ajouter">
    <span id="error-message" class="text-danger"></span>
    <span id="success-message" class="text-success"></span>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(() => {
  var itsChecked = null

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', () => {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
      //S'il y a au moins 1 ([...].length > 0) ckecked
      alert('At least one is checked')
      itsChecked = 1
      $('#GL').removeAttr("required")
      $('#SI').removeAttr("required")
      $('#IM').removeAttr("required")
      $('#SIRI').removeAttr("required")
    } else {
      //S'il n'y a aucun checked (!(at least 1)>0)
      alert('None is checked')
      itsChecked = 0
      $('#GL').attr('required', '')
      $('#SI').attr('required', '')
      $('#IM').attr('required', '')
      $('#SIRI').attr('required', '')

    }
  })

  $('#submit').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const titre = $('#intitule').val()
    const domaine = $('select[name=categorie]').val()
    let filiereChecked = []

    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), (i, elem) => {
      filiereChecked.push($(elem).val())
    })
    const checked = filiereChecked.join(", ")
    const desc = $('#description').val()
    alert(itsChecked)

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0)) {
        $('#error-message').html('')
        $('#success-message').fadeIn().html(xhr.responseText)
        setTimeout( () => {
          $('#success-message').fadeOut('slow')
        }, 2000)
        $('form').trigger('reset')
      }
    }
    if (titre === '' || domaine === '' || itsChecked === null || itsChecked === 0 || desc === '') {
      $('#error-message').fadeIn().html('Tous les champs sont requis')
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('#error-message').fadeOut('slow')
      }, 2000)
      xhr.abort()
    } else {
      const url = "{{ route('themes.store') }}"
      const formValues = $("form").serialize()
      xhr.open('POST', url, true)
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      alert('form sent')
      xhr.send(formValues)
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

Et voilà, this achieves what you need. Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fn43qkL9/5/).

Comment: Thank you guy ! This is working. Yeah, indeed, the logic I used wasn't good; especially that last part with the else statement; your if else with the send method in the else did the trick. Thanks again